# Hibernate: Additional query on MySQL when not on Hypersonic

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

Does anybody have any clue why Hibernate makes an additional query if I am using MySQL and doesn't make it when I am using Hypersonic?

I have such structure:

```
A has set of B and link to C
B has link to C
```

Everywhere in mappings I am using fetch="join". When I am asking for A then on Hypersonic it is one big query but when I am using MySQL then it is additional query for C which comes from resolving B.

A difference in logs for Hibernate debug is that in case of MySQL I don't have "result row: EntityKey[C#101]" from the first query. For Hypersonic there is: "result row: EntityKey[A#101], EntityKey[B#101], EntityKey[C#101]. For MySQL there is no EntityKey for C.

Comment: do you have the same data in both db ?

Comment: yes, I have the same data.